# Jquery-how to move some selectable div into left ,on click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some div which is selectable on click its .then i have two button the purpose of this button is when i select some div and click the left button the div moves left into 20px. The right button for the reverse process.
my requirement is 
      1.after select the when i click left button the div move into 20px left (thats now working)
    2. on second click it moves to 40px(means 20px from the current position)
    how can i do this?

```js
        $("#key").click(function myfunction() {
            $("div.toGrab").css("padding-left", '');
            $("div.selected").css("padding-left", '20px');
        });
        $("#key1").click(function myfunction() {
            $("div.toGrab").css("padding-left", '');
            $("div.selected").css("padding-left", '0px');
        });
        $("div.toGrab").on("click", function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    
    <style>
        div{
            background-color:yellow;
            margin-top:20px;
        }
        div {

}
.selected {
  background: green;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="key">left</button>
    <button id="key1">right</button>

    
    <div class='toGrab'>grand parent</div>
    <div class='toGrab'>parent</div>
    <div class='toGrab'>child</div>
    <div class='toGrab'>child</div>
    <div class='toGrab'>child</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this help you

Improved version

Shifts the element 20 pixels from the position where he was

```
function positioningSelectedItems(obj){
    var negative = obj.negative || false;
    var padding = obj.padding || 20;
    $("div.selected").each(function (key,val) {
        if(!negative)
            var spad = parseFloat($(val).css("padding-left"))+padding;
        else
            var spad = parseFloat($(val).css("padding-left"))-padding;
        $(val).css("padding-left", spad+'px')
    });
}

$("#key").click(function myfunction() {
    positioningSelectedItems({negative:false});
});
$("#key1").click(function myfunction() {
    positioningSelectedItems({negative:true});
});
$("div.toGrab").on("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: it is working but the un selecetd div return to first position on second click..how can i solve this problem

Comment: I Improved my answer,please check it

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".toGrab").on("click", function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
$("#key").click(function(){
var sl = parseInt($(".selected").css("padding-left"));
$(".selected").css({
      paddingLeft : "+="+"20"
});
if(sl >= '100'){
      $(".selected").css({
      paddingLeft : 100
});
}
});
$("#key1").click(function(){
    $(".selected").css({
      paddingLeft : "-="+"20"
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: this code is more useful for me,and one think how can i stop this function when the position reach 60px?

Comment: @aswathy check updated code, there is some other method too so that it stop certain event onclick, will update that.

Comment: its perfect ,but why its not working when i change maximum left value more than 60?

Comment: if you change >= 60 value to 80 and paddinLeft to 80, it stop or set you stop position to 80.

Comment: ya i also change padding-left>=80 and paddingleft:80
but its not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116250/discussion-between-frnt-and-aswathy).

Answer (score 1):

Keep a variable

```
(function($)){



    $("#key").click(function myfunction() {
        var position= parseInt($("div.toGrab").css("padding-left"));
        position+=20;
        $("div.toGrab").css("padding-left", '');
        $("div.selected").css("padding-left", position+'px');
    });
    $("#key1").click(function myfunction() {
         var position= parseInt($("div.toGrab").css("padding-left"));
        position -=20;
        $("div.toGrab").css("padding-left", '');
        $("div.selected").css("padding-left", position+'px');
    });
    $("div.toGrab").on("click", function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });
})($);
```

Comment: now it is working but the un selecetd div return to first position on second click..how can i solve this problem

Comment: try now if u can provide a fiddle it would be gr8